# Performance issue with fresh install MySQL 5.616-1~exp1 (Ubuntu) on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: mysql, performance, ubuntu-16.04, mysql5.6

I've recently started on a new company and I'm currently setting my dev environment.

We're using Ubuntu 16.04 and MySQL 5.6

Everything was right until I launched the tests (using `mvn test`). After waiting more tan 20 minutes, the tests were not finished. I commented it with my pals, and they've told me that for them it usually takes no more than 7 minutes for all tests to end. Even more, our CI machine (that should be worst than my laptop), runs all tests on more or less 6 minutes. I don't even know how much it takes for me as I'm trying different approaches and stop execution after 15 minutes. I'm completely lost here.

I'm starting to think that it's something related to buffers or something like that. This is the server performance dashboard on mysqlworkbench for my machine (notice the performance peak, after which it continues at 7 queries per second):
[image]

And this is the CI server's one (notice the continuos +500 queries per second and 22K InnoDB read requests):

[image]

My laptop is a Lenovo Z50 with intel core i7, 8Gb RAM and a hybrid SSD drive.

**UPDATE**

After some tinkering on the tests code, I've found that if I only setup and tearDown the dataset in only 50% of the tests, the server gets better results (still lower than on the server). This may indicate some problem with buffers?

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Configuration was none, as it was a fresh installation. Now `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` have the following (after blindly trying some options):

```
[mysqld]
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
innodb_adaptive_flushing
innodb_adaptive_hash_index
innodb_checksums = off
innodb_doublewrite
innodb_use_native_aio
```

Not sure if I should look into another config file.

Comment: Please share your MySQL configuration.